# Save to Drive API: Automatically convert to Google Docs format

Tags: google-drive-api

I don't think it's possible, but thought it was worth asking if it's possible to use the [Save to Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive) and have a document automatically converted to the new format? It would be really useful if there was a parameter that we could specify that would allow this. We work with students that are downloading documents that they have to edit. Typically they're in .doc and .xls format. If we could auto convert those documents with the button for our students, it would be immensely helpful.

I did find this issue, but I'm not sure how related that is: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, sorry. It is really easy to open the file in Google Docs though. Google rather you use a copy than potentially change the fidelity of the file you are storing.

Comment: Thanks but what about this case.  I have a CSV file.  I use "Save to Drive" and it shows up as a file that I can only download.  How can I convert it to a spreadsheet without downloading it and re-uploading it?  Thanks.