# Make Save to Drive button convert a CSV to a Google Sheet

Tags: csv, google-drive-api

We are using the 'Save to Drive' button (https://developers.google.com/drive/savetodrive) on our web site to allow clients to save CSV exports to Google Drive.

Unfortunately, this saves the file to the drive but doesn't automatically convert it to a Google Sheet. This means that users have to click 'Open with Google Drive Viewer' and then 'File > Open with Google Sheets’ to convert the file to a spreadsheet in Google Drive. This makes for a poor experience for our users.

Is there a way to ask Google Drive to automatically convert these documents on import?  Also, if there is a better place to ask this question let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Question already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823876/save-to-drive-api-automatically-convert-to-google-docs-format